# Can't make search query work in Sanity CMS

Tags: content-management-system, sanity, groq

I am trying to perform a very basic search query with Sanity CMS.
This is how the `person` schema I've created looks like:

```js
export default {
  title: "Person",
  name: "person",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      title: "Name",
      name: "name",
      type: "string",
    }
  ]
}
```

I have entered two different Person data.
And this is how I try to fetch the data:

```js
const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: 'siaj5ql4',
  dataset: 'production',
  useCdn: true
})

const query = '*[_type == "person"]'

client.fetch(query).then(person => {
  console.log(person)
})
```

But I get an empty array like so in the console: `[]`
There is no error or anything.
Any ideas on this simple task?

Comment: The Sanity command line is a good tool for debugging issues like this. Bring up your terminal and cd to the folder where your code is running from. Type the following: `sanity documents query '*[_type=="person"]'`. Do you get any results?

Comment: @thomax Yes, I do. I also tried the exact same query on `vision` which is a sanity plugin for performing queries and it also returns the expected data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two common reasons for this:

1. The dataset is private and the client is not configured with a token.
2. The documents you expect to see is not published (drafts are private by default) and the client is not configured with a token.

Also note that the CDN can not be used with private datasets and/or access token.

Comment: You're right, the dataset was private and setting it public solved the problem. Are there any downsides with setting the dataset public when the CORS Origins are limited to specific URLs?

Comment: Glad it solved it for you! Making the dataset public means every published document in your dataset is publicly readable (CORS only matters in a browser context, and does not restrict anyone from e.g. crawling your dataset for all public documents).